# How do we calculate the Total Variation distance between two probability distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have $2$ probability distributions $P=(0,0,0.5,0.5$) and $Q=(0.5,0.5,0,0)$. That is, $P(1)=0$, $P(3)=0.5$, etc. We have $2$ formulas for the total variation distance:

$$TV(P,Q) = SUP(|Pi-Qi|) = 0.5$$

and

$$TV(P,Q) = L1(P-Q)/2 = 1$$

Why do they give different results?

Comment: You forgot a $\frac12$ factor: $\mathrm{TV}(P,Q)=\frac12\|P-Q\|_1$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures#Relation_to_other_distances).

Comment: Note that I divide by 2 which is equivalent.

Comment: Indeed. @nejimban, Raymond did not forget that $\frac12$ factor. Btw, I wonder why the close votes (not from you).

Comment: Good catch, and sorry, I should have read more carefully (even if it was not typeset in LaTeX!)

Answer (score 2):

$$\operatorname{TV}(P,Q)\ne\sup_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}|P_i-Q_i|=0.5.$$

$$\operatorname{TV}(P,Q)=\sup_{A\subset\{1,2,3,4\}}|P(A)-Q(A)|=1.$$

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot!